# Why does not onReleased fire up after a drag

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a mouse area that has something like this

```
onPressed: {
  cursorShape = Qt.ClosedHandCursor
  console.log("closed")
}

onReleased: {
  cursorShape = Qt.OpenHandCursor
  console.log("open")
}

cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor
```

If I click and release without any mouse movement, the cursor icon changes as expected. If I move the mouse while clicked though, the cursor icon remain a closed hand.

Why is that?

Comment: Make sure to also handle onCanceled. Alternatively, use onPressedChanged

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld onCancelled cannot possibly resolve the issue because it will fire up right at the moment of the drag, and onReleased again will not fireup. And onPressedChanged does not take into consideration when the mouse is released again. It is odd that onReleased does not get emitted if you move the mouse.

Comment: Is it odd? It's pretty standard to me. Quoting the `clicked()` documentation - "This signal is emitted when there is a click. A click is defined as a press followed by a release, both inside the MouseArea (pressing, moving outside the MouseArea, and then moving back inside and releasing is also considered a click)". AFAIK that's a common usage in other languages too. If you don't like it just change the cursor in another handler, e.g. `onPositionChanged()` since "By default this signal is only emitted if a button is currently pressed." or any other suitable.

Comment: One would expect the release signal to get emitted when I release the mouse button, no matter if I decided to move it while pressing it. That is why I called this behavior odd.

Comment: Sorry I've understand that you wanted a release while a movement start. Which would be really odd. :) Indeed documentation agrees with us and I'd say it smells like a bug of some sort.

Comment: I thought about it being a bug too. But I have found so many that I am afraid they will just ban me from any Qt related sites for ever :)
Just to be clear Qt is awesome btw.

Comment: No ban. Just report it. Qt is awesome, Qt is buggy. Both statements are indeed true. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked the behaviour is right with the following code in QML .

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainwindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        width: 200; height: 200
        contentWidth: image.width
        contentHeight: image.height
        clip: true

        Image {
            id: image;
            source: "images/icon.png"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                preventStealing: true

                onPressed: {
                  cursorShape = Qt.ClosedHandCursor
                  console.log("closed")
                }

                onReleased: {
                  cursorShape = Qt.OpenHandCursor
                  console.log("open")
                }

                cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting [preventStealing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#preventStealing-prop) as `true` gets the `MouseArea` working fine and the `cursorShape` changes ok. But the drawback (a BIG drawback) is the flick gesture is stolen by the `MouseArea` so the flick movement is not generated.

So, I recommend handling `onMovementEnded` to set the `cursorShape = Qt.OpenHandCursor` when the user interaction ends.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainwindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Flickable {
        width: 200; height: 200
        contentWidth: image.width
        contentHeight: image.height
        clip: true

        onMovementEnded: {
            mousearea.cursorShape = Qt.OpenHandCursor
            console.log("onMovementEnded")
        }

        Image {
            id: image;
            source: "images/icon.png"

            MouseArea {
                id: mousearea
                anchors.fill: parent

                onPressed: {
                    cursorShape = Qt.ClosedHandCursor
                    console.log("closed")
                }

                onReleased: {
                    cursorShape = Qt.OpenHandCursor
                    console.log("open")
                }

                cursorShape: Qt.OpenHandCursor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For 5.5 this did not work for me. My mouse area is inside an Image, that is inside a Flickable. But this should not effect the press event normally.

Comment: I didn't know you had the `MouseArea` inside an `Image`. I've updated the code. In this case, we need to set [preventStealing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#preventStealing-prop) as `true`. If not, the behaviour is odd indeed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that setting preventStealing as true, the flick gesture is not triggered. So I've updated again the code with another solution.

Comment: This of curse solves the issue described, thus I am marking it as the correct answer. I had forgotten about the existence of `onMovementEnded`.

Comment: @green_leaf Nice :) Thank you and happy coding! :)

Comment: Ahhh...the `Flickable` was in the way. Next time you should put all the pieces in place @green_leaf  :) I think that somewhere in the documentation this usage of `preventStealing` is documented, though.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo indeed quite stupid of me. Actually yes, there is a mention on that in the docs for [MouseArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-mousearea.html). But again as Tarod pointed there is an issue if you want both functionalities.